# Django use context variable passed from view in the url pattern

Tags: python, django

I have a view function passing in an integer as a context and renders a HTML file.

```
def youtube(request, gateid=0):
    print(gateid)
    return render(request, "streamapp/youtube.html", {'gateid': gateid})
```

Inside the HTML file called youtube.html, I want to use this argument gateid inside a URL pattern which calls in another view.
existing code: `<a href='{% url 'video_feed' gateid=0 %}' />`

So instead of hard coding the `gateid=0` to zero in the above `<a />` tag, I wanna make use of the context variable passed, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `gateid` variable, so:

```
<a href="{% url 'video_feed' gateid=gateid %}">
```

Comment: I was super dumb and was accessing the gateid inside flower brackets. Thanks for the solution